# Send OpenGL video flux via UDP

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, udp

It is possible to send the video flux of an OpenGL desktop app via UDP **on Linux** ? I looked up [FBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and off-screen rendering but still can't figure out how to extract the video flux and send it.

I'm working with C++ but if you have explanations in others langages go ahead.

EDIT : I figured out how to build the architecture here is my code

```
void getVideoStream(){
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);

    vector< unsigned char > buf( width * height * 3 );

    glPixelStorei( GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &buf[0] );

    // compress the image

    // send it via UDP
}
```

with `width` and `height` the dimension of your window.

Comment: What is a "video flux"?

Comment: By video flux I mean the frames generated by OpenGL. Should I change the title ?

Comment: @LittleStrongMind: Well, actually OpenGL doesn't generate "frames". It just draws point, lines and triangles. Ocassionally a glFinish or buffer swap denotes that sending drawing commands is complete and shall be executed. But after a finish/swap one can continue to draw on the front buffer. In that regard a OpenGL frame is "never" finishes. This is very unlike Direct3D, where in fact there is a clear definition of a frame.